# Last 12 months of data for each item/row from the selected date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to identify last 12 months of data for each item in each row. For eg: if A item has dateperiod:1/12/2021. it will provide an output as Qty: 23 which covers from 11/2021 to 12/2020

How can I write Sql in Oracle to achieve this below result.
Four columns item, Qty, DatePeriod and 12 months Qty Value

Item    Qty DatePeriod  12 Months Qty Value
A   2   1/1/2020
A   3   1/2/2020
A   4   1/3/2020
A   1   1/4/2020
A   2   1/5/2020
A   2   1/6/2020
A   1   1/7/2020
A   2   1/8/2020
A   1   1/9/2020
A   2   1/10/2020
A   2   1/11/2020
A   2   1/12/2020
A   2   1/1/2021
A   3   1/2/2021
A   4   1/3/2021
A   1   1/4/2021
A   2   1/5/2021
A   2   1/6/2021
A   1   1/7/2021
A   2   1/8/2021
A   1   1/9/2021
A   2   1/10/2021   9/2021 to 10/2020 qty: 24
A   1   1/11/2021   10/ 2021 to 11/2020 Qty: 24
A   1   1/12/2021   11/2021 to 12/2020 Qty: 23
B   2   1/1/2020
B   2   1/2/2020
B   2   1/3/2020
B   5   1/4/2020
B   6   1/5/2020
B   2   1/6/2020
B   1   1/7/2020
B   2   1/8/2020
B   1   1/9/2020
B   2   1/10/2020
B   2   1/11/2020
B   2   1/12/2020
B   2   1/1/2021
B   1   1/2/2021
B   1   1/3/2021
B   1   1/4/2021
B   1   1/5/2021
B   2   1/6/2021
B   1   1/7/2021
B   2   1/8/2021
B   2   1/9/2021
B   3   1/10/2021   9/2021 to 10/2020 qty: 19
B   2   1/11/2021   10/ 2021 to 11/2020 Qty: 20
B   2   1/12/2021   11/2021 to 12/2020 Qty: 20

Answer (score 2):

To find the last 12 months data for each item (which may have different times for the latest items) then, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY item
  ORDER     BY DatePeriod DESC
  MEASURES
    LAST(dateperiod)  AS from_date,
    FIRST(dateperiod) AS to_date,
    SUM(qty)          AS total
  PATTERN (^ year+)
  DEFINE year AS dateperiod > ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(datePeriod), -12)
);
```

In earlier versions, you can use:

```sql
SELECT item,
       from_date,
       dateperiod AS to_date,
       total
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM(qty) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item
           ORDER BY dateperiod
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
                 AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
         ) AS total,
         MIN(dateperiod) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item
           ORDER BY dateperiod
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
                 AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
         ) AS from_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dateperiod DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item, Qty, DatePeriod) AS
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, DATE '2020-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2020-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2020-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 5, DATE '2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 6, DATE '2020-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2020-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2020-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2020-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, DATE '2021-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 3, DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ITEM | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 22 |
> | B | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 20 |

If you want to get the running totals for each row then you can use the `SUM` analytic function with a range window:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(qty) OVER (
         PARTITION BY item
         ORDER BY dateperiod
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
               AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
       ) AS last_year_total
FROM   table_name t
```

Which outputs:

> | ITEM | QTY | DATEPERIOD | LAST_YEAR_TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | A | 3 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
> | A | 4 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 9 |
> | A | 1 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 12 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 14 |
> | A | 1 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 15 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 17 |
> | A | 1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 18 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 22 |
> | A | 2 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 3 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 4 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 2 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 2 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 1 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 1 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 2 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 24 |
> | A | 1 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 23 |
> | A | 1 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 22 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 4 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 6 |
> | B | 5 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 11 |
> | B | 6 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 17 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 19 |
> | B | 1 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 22 |
> | B | 1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 23 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 25 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 27 |
> | B | 2 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 29 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 29 |
> | B | 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 28 |
> | B | 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 27 |
> | B | 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 23 |
> | B | 1 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 18 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 18 |
> | B | 1 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 18 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 18 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 19 |
> | B | 3 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
> | B | 2 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=360fc83d97a8d695784ee1ccf27f19e1)*

Comment: This is great. Below one is helpful to meet my requirement
SUM(qty) OVER (
         PARTITION BY item
         ORDER BY dateperiod
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
               AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
       ) AS last_year_total

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi,

Using same above data, I am also trying to get last year's 12 month to 9th month from the selection using the interval
SUM(qty) OVER ( PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dateperiod RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '8' MONTH FOLLOWING )

But it is not picking up the right value. Can you please help me on this as well

Eg:if the date is 202101, I am trying to get the data of 202002 to 202005.

Comment: @Raja `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '8' MONTH PRECEDING`

Comment: @MTO. Thanks once again for the help. It works for me, I should have tried PRECEDING at the first place.

Comment: Sorry to come up again with one more request,

Comment: sometimes, not all the 12 months of data is available, in that case, I have to dynamically add the available months of data within last 12 month data column.
Eg: with above data, if Item A: has no data at the date of 2021:Year- 01:Month, in that case, it has to add up the data from 2020-12 to 2020-02 and fill the result data of these 11 month for the period 2021:Year and 01 Month

Comment: Similarly,  if Item B: has no data at the date of 2021:Year- 01:Month and 06: month, it has to add up the whatever data available from 2020-12 to 2020-02 and fill the result data of these 10 month for the period 2021:Year and 01 Month


basically, even if there is no data from input table for any particular date, SQL query has to add values dynamically for that particular date and fill it in them.
Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @Raja Ask a new question with a [MRE] describing the problem. It sounds like you might want a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` but I'm not sure that I entirely understand your description from that couple of comments so it would be better to ask in a format where you can give a complete example.

Comment: @MT0- Sorry for confusing you. I explained with example in the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218833/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-with-values-of-last-12-months-of-data-when-particula

Please let me know if this is possible