# How to dynamically add rows with values of last 12 months of data when particular period is missing within the particular last 12 month period?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the input Table:

| ITEM | QTY | DATEPERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 3 | 2/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 4 | 3/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 1 | 4/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 5/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 6/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 8/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 10/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 12/1/2020 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 1/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 3 | 2/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 4 | 3/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 5/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 6/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 8/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 1 | 9/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 2 | 10/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 1 | 11/1/2021 0:00 |
| A | 1 | 12/1/2021 0:00 |

This input table does not have data of 2021-July, when I have to calculate the data of last 12 month for each rows, I will be able to get data of last 12 months from dec 2021 to Aug 2021.

But since the input table does not have data of 2021-July, using usual query

```sql
SUM(qty) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item
           ORDER BY dateperiod
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
                 AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
         ) AS total,
```

would generate last 12 month data for June 2021. But the expected output is even if the data is not available in July-2021, is it possible to dynamically generate a row as last 12 month data for July-2021 which should be from July 2021 to Aug 2020. The result of the qty is: 19

similarly, the input table is missing data for April 2021. Then the query generate a row as last 12 month data for April-2021 which should be from April 2021 to May 2020. The result of the qty is: 19

So the expected output will be in the form of

| ITEM | DATEPERIOD | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2020 | 2 |
| A | 2/1/2020 | 5 |
| A | 3/1/2020 | 9 |
| A | 4/1/2020 | 10 |
| A | 5/1/2020 | 12 |
| A | 6/1/2020 | 14 |
| A | 7/1/2020 | 14 |
| A | 8/1/2020 | 16 |
| A | 9/1/2020 | 16 |
| A | 10/1/2020 | 18 |
| A | 11/1/2020 | 18 |
| A | 12/1/2020 | 20 |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 20 |
| A | 2/1/2021 | 20 |
| A | 3/1/2021 | 20 |
| A | 4/1/2021 | 19 |
| A | 5/1/2021 | 19 |
| A | 6/1/2021 | 19 |
| A | 7/1/2021 | 19 |
| A | 8/1/2021 | 19 |
| A | 9/1/2021 | 20 |
| A | 10/1/2021 | 20 |
| A | 11/1/2021 | 21 |
| A | 12/1/2021 | 20 |

Please let me know if this is possible

Comment: Since I don't have a privilege to copy the image, I can't give exact format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to generate a calendar and the use an `OUTER JOIN` to join it to your data (however, since you are doing it for each `item` then you probably want a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`):

```sql
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(min_dp, LEVEL - 1) AS month
  FROM   (
    SELECT MIN(dateperiod) AS min_dp,
           MAX(dateperiod) AS max_dp
    FROM   table_name
  )
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(min_dp, LEVEL - 1) <= max_dp
)
SELECT item,
       c.month AS dateperiod,
       COALESCE(t.qty, 0) AS qty,
       SUM(t.qty) OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.item
           ORDER BY c.month
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING
                 AND     INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
         ) AS total
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.item)
       ON (c.month = t.dateperiod);
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ITEM, QTY, DATEPERIOD) AS
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, DATE '2020-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2020-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ITEM | DATEPERIOD | QTY | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
> | A | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 5 |
> | A | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 9 |
> | A | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 10 |
> | A | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 12 |
> | A | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 14 |
> | A | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 14 |
> | A | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 16 |
> | A | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 16 |
> | A | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 18 |
> | A | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 18 |
> | A | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 19 |
> | A | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 19 |
> | A | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 19 |
> | A | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 19 |
> | A | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 19 |
> | A | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 20 |
> | A | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 21 |
> | A | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d62f145ad7deba3bd0100530de2e1050)*

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me. You came again to save my day